# unable to open apps

Tags: 8.1, lumia-520

My phone was working pretty well.. but since morning i'm unable to open any app.. whenever i click on it it takes me back to start screen. All apps are working except downloaded apps. I uninstalled some of them but i'm unable to install them again. i tried soft reset but its of no use.. can you say any other solution apart from hard reset as soon as possible as i don't want to loose my data. Mine is windows 8.1 version

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your phone?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to soft reset your phone? If not, hold the volume down key and power key until your phone resets.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a couple years ago with my windows phone. Some apps were not booting and it seemed to be getting worse. I found an error code that I can't any longer reference. Doing a search on the error code revealed that a very old MS program from like 1996 was causing the error and there was no solution to the problem. I loved my windows phone, however along with the decreased user base and the talk that MS was about done with phones, I switched to a Samsung. Fixed the problem but I miss my Windows phone.